# map kind of asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, dictionary

I want to create a asp.net application which can show directions in a layout from room A to room B. So layout would be a grid of rooms and if the user wants to get directions from room A to room B the application to highlight the path in blue.

I have no idea how to begin with this? What can i use to create a floor layout and then highlight the required path. Any pointers ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can implement path-finding alghorithm , for example
A* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).
In case you describe,I would create a map as two-dimensional array that represents grid of passable and non passable "squares" - rooms and their walls in your case, and use A* algorithm to find shortest path on passable "squares". Then based on algorithm result I would generate the path in image like Daniel suggested.

I think [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm) tutorial can help to understand the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the path as an image, then here are a couple links on how to generate images in ASP.NET:

- [Generating Images Dynamically in ASP.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nagryum/generateimages07062007075701AM/generateimages.aspx)
- [Generating ASP.NET Images on the Fly](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/generating-asp-net-images-fly)